# How to improve this query - is partitioning the best option here?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called Transactions which currently contains 6+ million of rows (around 600-700 thousand per month)
It looks like this:

```
pk                                                           id          acct_id     id1         id2         id3         id4         created                 interface_id source_lvl1 source_lvl2 trans_type
------------------------------------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- ------------ ----------- ----------- -----------
10000257.4297...400245990.3.1002                             10000257    4297        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        2012-09-06 11:26:30.000 1            32002       1002        3
10004819.1529.106.105442.400667675.6.1021                    10004819    1529        106         105442      62          NULL        2012-09-11 08:34:35.000 4            32002       1021        6
10004819.1529.18664647.62.400667675.3.1021                   10004819    1529        18664647    62          NULL        NULL        2012-09-11 08:34:35.000 4            32002       1021        3
10006460.1529.106.105442.400667675.6.1021                    10006460    1529        106         105442      62          NULL        2012-09-11 08:34:35.000 4            32002       1021        6
10006460.1529.18664647.62.400667675.3.1021                   10006460    1529        18664647    62          NULL        NULL        2012-09-11 08:34:35.000 4            32002       1021        3
10006648.3280...406204785.3.1002                             10006648    3280        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        2012-11-14 10:39:45.000 6            32002       1002        3
10006834.1529.106.105442.400667675.6.1021                    10006834    1529        106         105442      62          NULL        2012-09-11 08:34:35.000 4            32002       1021        6
10006834.1529.18664647.62.400667675.3.1021                   10006834    1529        18664647    62          NULL        NULL        2012-09-11 08:34:35.000 4            32002       1021        3
10006962.2428...415795811.3.1018                             10006962    2428        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        2013-03-05 10:50:11.000 1            32002       1018        3
10006962.2428.107972..415795811.4.1018                       10006962    2428        107972      NULL        NULL        NULL        2013-03-05 10:50:11.000 1            32002       1018        4
```

I have defined a view which is supposed to facilitate counting specific events:

here is sql definition:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Queue_base]

AS

select 
dateadd(minute , (DATEPART(minute,t.created)/30)*30 , DATEADD(hour,datediff(hour, 0, t.created), 0)) INTRVL_UTC,
dateadd(minute , (DATEPART(minute,t.created)/30)*30 + 30 , DATEADD(hour,datediff(hour, 0, t.created), 0)) INTRVL_END_UTC,
a.ID [Agent ID], a.Login, a.DisplayName, a.GroupName, q.QueueID, q.QueueName, 
    TODATETIMEOFFSET(t.created,0) created   
,i.ReferenceNumber, t.id inc_id
, case when (t.trans_type=17 and t.source_lvl2 not IN (1001, 2001)) or (t.trans_type=6 and t.id1=8) then t.id else null end [Workload]
, case when (t.trans_type=6 and t.id1=8 and t.source_lvl2 not IN (1001, 2001) or (t.trans_type=17 and not t.source_lvl2 IN (1001,2001)))then t.id else null end [Inbound Emails]
, case when t.trans_type=17 and t.id1=q.QueueID then t.id else null end [EnQueued]
, case when t.trans_type=17 and t.id2=q.QueueID then t.id else null end [DeQueued]
, case when t.trans_type=6 and t.id1 IN (2,106) then t.id else null end [Solved]
, case when t.trans_type=6 and t.id1 =8 then t.id else null end [Updated]
, case when x.StatusTypeID = 2 then t.id else null end [Reopened]
, case when t.trans_type=6 and t.id1=125 then t.id else null end [Spam]
, case when t.trans_type=8 and t.acct_id <> 1 then t.id else null end [Responded]
, case when i.cr_rec_element_1 is not null or i.de_reason1 is not null then t.id else null end [Complaint]
,t.trans_type, t.id1
,r.Brand, r.Region, r.[Call Center], r.LOB, r.[LOB Detail], r.Team, r.Subteam, r.Channel
,r.Interface, r.Product, r.[Product Detail], r.Unit
from Transactions t 
left join
(
select a.*, b.id1, st.StatusTypeID
from
(select  
t1.pk, t1.id, t1.created,   max(t2.created) maxdate
from Transactions t1 
    left join Transactions t2 
    on t1.id=t2.id and t2.created<t1.created and t2.trans_type=6
 left join Status st on t2.id1=st.StatusID
 where t1.trans_type=6 and t1.id1=8
group by t1.pk, t1.id, t1.created) a left join Transactions b on a.id=b.id and b.created=a.maxdate and b.trans_type=6
left join Status st on b.id1=st.statusid
)
x on t.pk=x.pk
left join Incident i on t.id=i.id
left join Account a on t.acct_id=a.ID
left join Queue q ON  (t.trans_type=17 and (t.id1=q.QueueID or t.id2=q.QueueID) or t.trans_type IN (6,8) and t.id3=q.QueueID) 
left join queuedim r ON (q.QueueName=r.QueueName or q.QueueName is null and r.QueueName is null) 
    and (q.QueueID=r.QueueID or q.QueueID is null and r.QueueID is null)
where t.trans_type=17 or t.trans_type IN (6,8)
```

and this is the crucial part of the view:

```
inc_id      Workload    Inbound Emails EnQueued    DeQueued    Solved      Updated     Reopened    Spam        Responded   Complaint
----------- ----------- -------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
10209648    NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL        10209648    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
10209648    NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        10209648    NULL
10209648    10209648    NULL           NULL        NULL        NULL        10209648    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
10227966    NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        10227966    NULL        NULL
10288343    NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL        10288343    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
10303898    NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL        10303898    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
10394204    NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        10394204    NULL        NULL
10409624    NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL        10409624    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
10482071    NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        10482071    NULL        NULL
10485993    NULL        NULL           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        10485993    NULL        NULL
```

My plan was to create another table and successively update it with the aggregated results I am interested in, grouped by combinations of date periods and other dimensions. The thing is I need both distinct and simple counts of the events depicted above but, while the latter view yields its raw results pretty fast,  another query with counts takes ages:

```
    --  month   account
declare @d1 date
declare @d2 date

set @d1 = '2013-05-01'
set @d2 = '2013-06-01'
--insert into IncPerfQueue
select x.Brand, x.Region, x.[Call Center], x.LOB, x.[LOB Detail], x.Team, x.Subteam,
x.QueueName, case when x.[Agent ID] is null then 0 else [Agent ID] end,  c.[month], NULL weekstart, NULL [date]

, count(distinct EnQueued) [Distinct Incidents EnQueued]
, count(distinct DeQueued) [Distinct Incidents DeQueued]
, count(distinct Solved) [Distinct Incidents Solved in the queue]
, COUNT(distinct Responded) [Distinct Incidents Responded in the queue]
, COUNT(distinct Updated)   [Distinct Incidents Updated in the queue]
, count(distinct Reopened) [Distinct Incidents ReOpened in the queue]
, count(distinct Spam) [Distinct Spam closed in the queue]
, COUNT([Inbound Emails]) [Inbound Emails]
, COUNT(Workload) [Workload]
, count(EnQueued) [# EnQueued]
, count(DeQueued) [# DeQueued]
, count(Solved) [# Solved in the queue]
, COUNT(Responded) [# Responded in the queue]
, COUNT(Updated) [#Updated in the queue]
, count(Reopened) [# ReOpened in the queue]
, count(Spam) [# Spam closed in the queue]

from Queue_base x
join [calendar] c ON convert(date,x.created)=c.date
where x.created >= @d1 and x.created < @d2
and Brand is not null
group by x.Brand, x.Region, x.[Call Center], x.LOB, x.[LOB Detail], x.Team, x.Subteam,
x.QueueName, [Agent ID], c.month
```

This is just one of the required queries as separate aggregates for different dimensions are required (distinct counts per grouping), and it took over 1 hour!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWibJ.png

I will appreciate your suggestions as to what approach would be best in this sort of queries. The base table will surely grow much bigger soon... should I partition it? I should also note that all the tables referenced here are indexed and I am working with: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)(X64)
installed on a box equipped with 2x X5550 processors and 48GB RAM
the OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Thanks,
Maju

Comment: Partitioning it is definitely a good idea, specially so, if your queries will be date limited (that is to say, if most of your queries are for the current month, but not the rest, then you should create a partition based on month)

Comment: I'm a big fan of partitioning as a form of performance improvement, but you need to indicate what your indexing structure is first.  Your query may work reasonably well without partitioning if you index it appropriately.

Comment: As to indexing structure Transactions table has the following: pk (primary key), id, acct_id, created, id, id1, id2, trans_type, id3, source_lvl2 - all created with default non clustered indexes

Comment: Other tables are joined on primary keys. I am not an expert but I am not sure what exactly in indexing may have such adverse impact here. Apart from partitioning maybe my queries need a remake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your queries, I am guessing that a big portion of your costs are in the left joins and group by's. You probably can't do much about the left joins without sacrificing correctness, but I would take a look at your query plan to see how much those group by's cost.

Since you have millions of rows, I would guess that the sorts in your query plan take up 90+% of the time. Adding a few indices on those group by columns would really help to convert those sorts into index scans. Scanning that index would surely be faster than sorting, effectively recreating those indices each time. If you can post your query plan, that would be very helpful. It may be helpful for you to have a smaller version of the data (maybe a few thousand rows from each table) so that you can play around with indexing without waiting a long time to create them.

I don't think partitioning is necessary to bring down your query time. Partitioning only helps at the IO level. Since you are talking a few million rows, I am guessing that all together, all of the relevant columns of all relevant tables is only a few gigabytes. It would take a few minutes to load this from disk, but not an hour. Surely SQL Server would keep most of this stuff in memory while it's servicing an hour long query. Thus, partitioning would not be of much help here. Once your query plan doesn't have any more hot spots, and you see that io is a bottleneck in your query, then I would consider partitioning.

You can check IO with set statistics io on (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I did play around with partitions but it did not prove to be helpful. So I went on with intermediate table instead of the view (Queue_base) out of which I then populate aggregated calculations into the final table.

I agree good indexes design and usage could be crucial in improving my queries. Nevertheless the intermediate tables seems sufficient in my case.

Comment: @Maju I agree that an intermediate table would help. However, someone needs to keep the table up to date. I would recommend using a view instead, so that SQL Server would keep it up to date for you. You can even index the view in SQL Server.

Comment: Yeah, scheduled jobs do that, but obviously a view would be better in a sense that in conjunction with mapping tables it would always yield correct results whilst a pre-populated table might require rebuild each time the mapping error is spotted. Will experiment with new indexes/views when I have time...